# Как правильно писать полное название организации?

Tags: склонение

Как правильно: "техническая станция - структурное подразделение районной дирекции - структурное подразделение центральной дирекции", надо ли во втором случае "структурное" просклонять в родительном падеже "структурного"?

Answer (score 1):

Если имеется в виду, что структурное подразделение районной дирекции является структурным подразделением центральной дирекции - я бы это последнее всё-таки поставил в родительном падеже. Иначе структура подчиненности двусмысленна.

Answer (score 0):

Это одно название или два? Какое-то запутанное предложение! Что здесь является названием - ***"структурное подразделение районной дирекции"***  или ***"техническая станция - структурное подразделение районной дирекции - структурное подразделение центральной дирекции"?***

Comment: Это полное название одной организации

Comment: Если это полное название организации, пишите так, как  зафиксировано в названии самой организации.